# How do I use the Angular CLI via the Git Bash terminal in Visual Code Studio?

Tags: git, bash, angular, visual-studio-code

I downloaded and installed Visual Studio Code (Windows 10).
I opened it and edited the VSC config to run git bash.
I installed angular/cli (1.3.2) globally, via the bash terminal in VSC. When I ran 'ng new file-name' in the terminal, it returned an error similar to the one below.
I thought that the problem was installing with git bash via VSC, so I globally uninstalled Angular with the bash terminal, and then opened a console in Windows and globally installed angular/cli, again, and ran the 'ng new file-name' in the Windows console, which worked.

So I went back into VSC, but when I ran 'ng serve', it said:

```
$ ng serve
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
```

Should Angular be getting called out of a \Git\ folder? I looked around in the VSC config to see if there was some path I was supposed to edit, but I couldn't find one.

Or perhaps something in the way I installed it created a problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use tag angular for angular 2 questions. Tag angularjs is for version 1.x

Comment: Which version of the angular-cli did you use? `ng --version`

Comment: I have @angular/cli: 1.3.2